# innerHTML and html:select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I'm using JavaScript to add drop down in the jsp by clicking a button but somehow its not working. Can someone please help me. I need to use html:select tag.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
    function addRow() {
        var mytbody = document.getElementById('mytbody');
        var row = document.createElement('tr');
        var cell1 = document.createElement('td');

        cell1value='';
        cell1value+='<html:select property="test1" styleId="test1"> <html:option value="code1">test 1</html:option> </html:select>';    
        cell1.innerHTML = cell1value;       

         row.appendChild(cell1);    
         mytbody.appendChild(row);
    }
</script>
```

html codes:

```
<table id="mytable">
<tbody id="mytbody">
<tr>
    <td>test1</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" onclick="addRow()" value="test"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do you mean "its not working"?  Are you getting an error?  Please elaborate on the issue.

Comment: Please paste generated code as seen in your browser source, not the jsp code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

I made a jsfiddle to check it out... I think you might just need to have this javascript in the head tag.

Use F12 developer tools and try to debug the issue when you click the button. You might find that addRow() is undefined.

I also changed the code a little bit due to the fact that I am not versed in JSP - sorry! Is that what the

```
"<html:select..."
```

string was? I changed it to straight up html.

http://jsfiddle.net/e7z1efgr/

```js
function addRow() {
  var mytbody = document.getElementById('mytbody');
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  var cell1 = document.createElement('td');

  var cell1value = '';
  cell1value += '<select class="text1"><option value="code1">test 1</option></select>';
  cell1.innerHTML = cell1value;

  row.appendChild(cell1);
  mytbody.appendChild(row);
}
```

```html
<table id="mytable">
  <tbody id="mytbody">
    <tr>
      <td>test1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="addRow()" value="test" />
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: html:select is the strut tag which parse the regular html select codes

Comment: Ah I see. In that case, everything you've posted looks great. The only thing I can say from here is to use the developer tools of whatever browser you prefer to debug the javascript. The fiddle works, but if you change how the javascript is loaded it breaks it. OnDOMLoad, OnDocumentReady both break the button click.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the strange HTML you are inserting:

```
'<html:select property="test1" styleId="test1"> <html:option value="code1">test 1</html:option> </html:select>'
```

should be

```
'<select property="test1" styleId="test1"> <option value="code1">test 1</option> </select>'
```

Comment: it worked fine with the regular html select tags but i need to use the strut html:select tag in my jsp. So html:select tag will parse the html select tag.

Answer (score -1):

What's the purpose? If you just need it to insert rows inside the table, it works fine already:

```
Look here:
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGNJrV

Can you elaborate the question please?

Comment: I was trying to add a row by clicking the button but in the new row i have few drop downs as well. To sort out the issue i am adding just one drop down using html:select tag. When i click the button it shows a syntax error in the browser and issues shows with this lines -> cell1value+='<html:select property="test1" styleId="test1"> <html:option value="code1">test 1</html:option> </html:select>';